# can't merge dataframes on date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes which are like these:

left:

```
        date    B   N   S   yesterday_B   yesterday_N    yesterday_S
0   2021-01-03  4   99  0       3.0         80.0             0.0
1   2021-01-04  3   78  0       4.0         99.0             0.0
2   2021-01-05  0   50  0       3.0         78.0             0.0
3   2021-01-06  2   50  0       0.0         50.0             0.0
4   2021-01-07  2   10  0       2.0         50.0             0.0
```

right:

```
 finish  yesterday change day_t-2   date
0   11900   12230   -1    12850.0   2021-01-03
1   12150   11900   1     12230.0   2021-01-04
2   11640   12150   -1    11900.0   2021-01-05
3   11100   11640   -1    12150.0   2021-01-06
4   10620   11100   -1    11640.0   2021-01-09
```

and I wanna join these two on 'date' column by this code:

```
df = pd.merge(left, right, on='date', how='left')
```

but unfortunately, I get this result:

```
index   date                                                                                      
                                                                                              B N   S   yesterday_B yesterday_N yesterday_S finish_price    yesterday_price price_change    price_day_t-2
0   0 2021-01-03 1 2021-01-04 2 2021-01-05 3 2021-01-06 4 2021-01-07 ... 502 2022-06-06 503 2022-06-07 504 2022-06-08 505 2022-06-09 506 2022-06-10 Name: date, Length: 507, dtype: datetime64[ns]  4   99  0   3.0 80.0    0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   0 2021-01-03 1 2021-01-04 2 2021-01-05 3 2021-01-06 4 2021-01-07 ... 502 2022-06-06 503 2022-06-07 504 2022-06-08 505 2022-06-09 506 2022-06-10 Name: date, Length: 507, dtype: datetime64[ns]  3   78  0   4.0 99.0    0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   0 2021-01-03 1 2021-01-04 2 2021-01-05 3 2021-01-06 4 2021-01-07 ... 502 2022-06-06 503 2022-06-07 504 2022-06-08 505 2022-06-09 506 2022-06-10 Name: date, Length: 507, dtype: datetime64[ns]  0   50  0   3.0 78.0    0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   0 2021-01-03 1 2021-01-04 2 2021-01-05 3 2021-01-06 4 2021-01-07 ... 502 2022-06-06 503 2022-06-07 504 2022-06-08 505 2022-06-09 506 2022-06-10 Name: date, Length: 507, dtype: datetime64[ns]  2   50  0   0.0 50.0    0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   0 2021-01-03 1 2021-01-04 2 2021-01-05 3 2021-01-06 4 2021-01-07 ... 502 2022-06-06 503 2022-06-07 504 2022-06-08 505 2022-06-09 506 2022-06-10 Name: date, Length: 507, dtype: datetime64[ns]  2   10  0   2.0 50.0    0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

why can't it distinguish the date? what is the solution? I have converted datetime to string beofre.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider parsing them in the correct format. Are you sure there are no more columns or additional content?

```
left['date'] = pd.to_datetime(left['date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
right['date'] = pd.to_datetime(right['date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
```

And then try:

```
output = left.merge(right,on='date',how='left')
```

Comment: Doesn't `merge` work without converting `date` from `str` to `datetime`? It worked for my case, but OP claims otherwise..

Comment: Yes, it may work without the need to convert to datetime, but there's isn't just enough information to fully understand the issue. If parsing them correctly to datetime still generates error, then the issue is somewhere else and not correctly shown in the question.

Comment: Okay, I now realized the real issue in the OPs case is probably one of the `date` is `datetime` while other is not